# Why doesn't copying to clipboard in Cygwin work here?

Tags: bash, windows-10, cygwin

This works:

```
curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} $URL | xargs printf "%s" > /dev/clipboard
```

whereas this doesn't:

```
curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} $URL > /dev/clipboard
```

Why is that?

Comment: maybe as the curl output is seen as multiple items ? try ` > filename` and looks at its content.

Comment: `> filename` did work; although I don't understand why the output is seen as multiple items (it's a URL). Thanks. Could you add this as an answer?

Comment: If I capture the output using `> filename`, then `cat filename > /dev/clipboard` does work as expected...

Comment: My guess: `curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} $URL` exit with something else than success. Try `curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} $URL || echo -e "\nFAIL'`. Anyway it shouldn't prevent clipboard update. Seems that curl is messing with fd.

Comment: @Zilog80 curl does print out **both:** the final URL *and* "FAIL"

Comment: @markvgti That curl likes the URL or not doesn't change anything for /dev/clipboard. I guess there is fd  overwrite with curl. Can you try `curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{stderr}%{url_effective} $URL &> /dev/clipboard` if your curl client support it ?

Comment: That didn't work. I have `curl 7.55.1 (Windows) libcurl/7.55.1 WinSSL Release-Date: 2017-11-14, security patched: 2019-11-05`.

Comment: @markvgti Can you get a 7.70+ and test with it ? (there is at least a 7.74 in the cygwin depots)

Answer (score 1):

two possible solutions

```
curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} $URL > filename
cat filename > /dev/clipboard
```

and

```
curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} $URL | putclip
```

`putclip` is in

```
$ cygcheck -f /usr/bin/putclip
cygutils-extra-1.4.16-2
```